# Template 1.4.1 - How to render the same layout without retyping all write command

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to web development and I have simple question regarding Template 1.4.1.

I have 7 regions as shown below. My default controller renders those regions in template and it was good (See index method below). However, I would like to see the same layout, but with different content. Exactly the same except for content region.

I am wondering if there's a way I can achieve what I want without writing again the same command in index method. A one liner code probably or two. Can you show me how?

I tried the override in write_view and I can't make it work or I misunderstood the use of it. See add function below.

```
    $template['default']['regions'] = array(
       'headerstyles',
       'header',
       'banner',
       'rightfilter',
       'content',
       'scripts',
       'footer',
    );
```

Index method

```
    public function index()
     {
        $this->template->write_view('headerstyles', 'headerStyles');
        $this->template->write_view('header', 'header');
           $this->template->write_view('scripts', 'scripts');
           $this->template->render();
     }
```

Add function. addItem is existing and elements in addItem is rendered but without the other regions.

```
    public function add()
        {
            $this->template->write_view('content','addItem','',true);
            $this->template->render();
        }
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

wow you remind me early stage of using this library in CI, its really old library and you have to repeat code again and again. i will suggest you to use this template library by phil its better and easy to use and you can take advantage of OOP make things really simple. try this library and read the user guide in it.

https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-template

Comment: Thanks @umefarooq! I'll take a look on what you suggested. I assume phil's template will not repeat the entire process of rendering the view. Thank you very much!